# removeattr required not working chrome browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I am trying to remove required attribute from some hidden fields.

```
 $('#divQ9, #divQ10, #divQ11, #divQ12, #divQ13, #divQ14, #divQ15').find('input[type=radio]').removeAttr('required');
```

The above code works in all other browsers except Chrome with version < 50

Please suggest any work around for the same.

Comment: You can try `.prop('required', false)`

Comment: Have you tried with removeProp?

Comment: You can use prop function

Comment: Yes tried with these .prop & removeProp they are not working.

Comment: How are you determining that it isn't working?  You won't see your HTML change.  You will just see the behavior change.

Comment: I am getting this error 'An invalid form control with name='name' is not focusable.' in console

Comment: That error seems unrelated to this code sample

Answer (score 0):

Using the `.prop('required', false)` like Satpal says

https://jsfiddle.net/moongod101/j4xtvw2h/